# Why only one image shows in viewflipper using Json data by a ListArray?

Tags: android, json, android-volley, viewflipper

How to show the Json images in viewflipper in a listarray,logcat shows that it fetches all the images from the listarray but only one image shows on the emulator, why?
This is part of my code

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.ViewFlipper01);
        viewFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.fade_in));
        viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.fade_out));

 Log.d("VIEWFLIPPER size", String.valueOf(listSuperHeroes.size()));

                        for (int i = 0; i < listSuperHeroes.size(); i++) {
                            Log.d("VIEWFLIPPER PICS ", listSuperHeroes.get(i).getflag());
                            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
                            Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
                                    .load(listSuperHeroes.get(i).getflag())
                                    .centerCrop()
                                    .dontAnimate()
                                    .placeholder(R.drawable.logofresh)
                                    .into(imageView);
                            viewFlipper.addView(imageView);
                        }
                        viewFlipper.setAutoStart(true);
                        viewFlipper.setFlipInterval(3000);
```

LOGCAT

```
D/VIEWFLIPPER size: 10
D/VIEWFLIPPER PICS: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/china.png
D/VIEWFLIPPER PICS: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/india.png
D/VIEWFLIPPER PICS: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/unitedstates.png
D/VIEWFLIPPER PICS: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/indonesia.png
D/VIEWFLIPPER PICS: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/brazil.png
D/VIEWFLIPPER PICS: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/pakistan.png
D/VIEWFLIPPER PICS: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/nigeria.png
D/VIEWFLIPPER PICS: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/bangladesh.png
D/VIEWFLIPPER PICS: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/russia.png
D/VIEWFLIPPER PICS: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/japan.png
```

Comment: where are you changing image of flipper?

Comment: .load(listSuperHeroes.get(i).getflag())  /////This is the listArray, in here